# Can I control the flow of a 12 V power supply with a 4.5 V power supply and an IRF3205 MOSFET?

Tags: voltage, mosfet, switches

To start I am very much a beginner at electronics and am very limited in my tools.

I bought an [IRF3205](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRF3205-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355def244190a) MOSFET a few days ago hoping that I could use it in a circuit I have where a 12 V power supply at 1.5 A is capable of going from the source to the drain to turn on an LED light strip.

The MOSFET would be controlled by 4.5 V supplied by three AAA batteries at its gate.

I was disappointed though to test it and see that this MOSFET only outputted less than 9 V at the drain (I don't have a way of finding its current).

Is there a way to make this MOSFET work or do I need to buy a new one? If I need a new MOSFET, can I get a recommendation?

Again, my goal is to control an LED strip running at 12 V, 1.5 A with a 4.5 V battery supply going on and off with as few parts as possible, preferably just a single MOSFET and no resistors or capacitors.

Comment: Does not look like a logic level MOSFET, it won't turn on very well with only 4.5Vgs. But why would you want to use batteries to drive the gate when you have 12V available anyway? Sounds like a XY problem.

Comment: You're going to have to draw the schematic before anyone can help.

Comment: Can you provide the circuit you used? The IRF3205 has a gate threshold voltage of 2-4 volts. In worst case, it might be tight getting to 4.0 with 3 AAA batteries, but generally, should should be able to turn the MOSFET on and off. Also, you have 12V available. Why do you want to use a separate power supply to turn the MOSFET on and off?

Comment: Very unlikely you are turning the device on adequately with 4.5 V...that is barely over the threshold voltage.  It will be enough to get some current, but the drain to source resistance is killing you.  Try upping the voltage, or use a logic-level MOSFET.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Reaching the threshold voltage doesn't turn the MOSFET on like a switch, the drain to source resistance will be quite high.

Comment: @evildemonic could you recommend a logic level mosfet that will work in this situation?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy The reason I must use the 4.5 power supply is that it comes from a pic16F15345 micro chip which can handle a max of 5V

Comment: But you _have_ 12 volts. So, you would like to turn on/off your 12V with a digital level signal, using your mosfet, is that the only requirelment?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I would like to turn it off and on under the logic of my microchip, so yes if that is what you mean.

Comment: @KidWithComputer I would like to recommend a few to you, but that would go against the rules and intent of this site.  Use a parametric search at a distributer like Digi-Key and search for the keywords 'logic level'.  It would also be good for you to learn to interpret the charts on those datasheets that show the drain-source current curves based on Vgs.

Comment: @evildemonic that's what I did, and well you see where my mosfet buying capabilities got me, these specific ones said they would were for Arduinos, which can only produce 5V.

Comment: @KidWithComputer Do you care whether the load is switched on the high side or on the ground side? That is, do you care whether the MOSFET is between your load and the +12V supply, or can it be between the load and ground?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I'd prefer ground side but high side would work as well

Comment: @KidWithComputer Psst, here ya go kid, just remember you didn't get [these](https://tinyurl.com/ya2uzu64) from me.

Comment: Note the "drive voltage" and "Rds On" columns to see how I searched.

Comment: @evildemonic Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2):

This circuit may do what you hope for. Note that the 12V power is "normally on". That is, if the logic circuit is off, the 12V power will be applied to the load. If you need it to be the other way, it will take more components I think.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frmTIy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

==EDIT==

@evildemonic rightly points out that the circuit above draws current when the LED string is off. There **is** a cmos low-to-high voltage level shifting circuit that can provide level shifting with very little quiescent current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYP45g.png)</sup>

This circuit is usually not worth implementing with discrete components. However, it (or something equivalent) is available in ICs such as TI's [CD4504B](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4504b-ep.pdf). A CD4504B in combination with the OP's power MOSFET would be a reasonable solution to driving a 12 V LED string from a 4.5-5 V signal.

Comment: Just a note:  This circuit will drain the batteries the entire time the lights are off.